# JavaFX cannot drag and drop

Tags: java, javafx

I have this interface:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    Text fileText = new Text("File:");

    TextField fileField = new TextField();
    fileField.setDisable(true);
    fileField.setMinWidth(250);
    fileField.setOnDragDropped(e -> {

        Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasFiles()){

            fileField.setText(db.getFiles().toString());
            success = true;

        }

        e.setDropCompleted(success);
        e.consume();

    });

    Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
    clearButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> fileField.setText(""));

    HBox hboxFile = new HBox();
    hboxFile.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    hboxFile.getChildren().addAll(fileText, fileField, clearButton);

    HBox.setMargin(fileText, new Insets(10));
    HBox.setMargin(fileField, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0));
    HBox.setMargin(clearButton, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hboxFile));
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

I want to activate drag and drop for `TextField`, when I drop an file over input, will appear location of file.

My problem is I cannot drop anything in interface.

When I drag file over input appear interdict sign:

[image]

This sign is present all over interface when I try to drag a file.

Comment: You need more than just `setOnDragDropped()`. I recommend searching for a basic tutorial on drag and drop (or any of the other questions here on SO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `onDragOver` property to enable copying/moving of the file. Like so:

```
fileField.setOnDragOver((e) -> {
    if (e.getGestureSource() != fileField && e.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
        e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
    }
    e.consume();
});
```

Furthermore, the line `fileField.setDisable(true);` disables you from being able to drop files on your TextField. Instead, do:

```
fileField.setEditable(false);
```

This will allow you to drag/drop files to set the text, but it won't let a user edit the text manually.
The complete testing code:

```
public class TestApp extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Text fileText = new Text("File:");

        TextField fileField = new TextField();
        fileField.setMinWidth(250);
        fileField.setPromptText("Drop file here");
        fileField.setOnDragOver((e) -> {
            if (e.getGestureSource() != fileField && e.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }
            e.consume();
        });
        fileField.setEditable(false);
        fileField.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasFiles()) {
                fileField.setText(db.getFiles().toString());
                success = true;
            }
            e.setDropCompleted(success);
            e.consume();
        });

        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
        clearButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> fileField.setText(""));

        HBox hboxFile = new HBox();
        hboxFile.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hboxFile.getChildren().addAll(fileText, fileField, clearButton);

        HBox.setMargin(fileText, new Insets(10));
        HBox.setMargin(fileField, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(clearButton, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hboxFile));
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The result:
[image: Text cannot be edited manually]
When dropped:
[image: Selected 3 folders and dropped into TextField]

Comment: Still not work, and interdict sign still appear even if with `setEditable(true)`.

Comment: @KunLun you need to remove `setDisable(true)`

Comment: I removed it. I copy-paste your code and for me not work. Interdict sign appear.

Comment: @KunLun Well, something is wrong with your code then. Beyond `Application.launch(args)` in my main method, I literally have nothing else, and my test application works 100% fine. I've posted the full code for you to look at.

Comment: Same for me. I added a gif in my question(interface is with your code). This could be from IDE(Intellij)?

Comment: @KunLun That is extremely weird. I'm using OpenJFX version 13.0.0 on Java 12 on Windows, so it may be related to your version of JavaFX/your OS. Otherwise, I have no idea why this might be.

Comment: I use Java 10 Oracle on Windows 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200024/discussion-between-avi-and-kunlun).

Comment: The problem was from IDE(Intellij). If I export project as runnable jar, it works.